# Why isn't border-spacing adding padding around my TABLE element?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I'd like to have some padding above and below my TABLE element.  I've read that border-spacing can be used for this.  So I have my table

```
<table id="ranks">
    <tbody><tr class="ranksHeaderRow">
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Votes Cast</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ranksDataRow even" data-id="25">
        <td>1</td> 
        <td><a class="rankPersonLink" href="/votes/25">NameN</a></td>
        <td>12.0</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

and then had this style

```
#ranks {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 60%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

but there's no padding around the TABLE -- https://jsfiddle.net/00tjhxaw/ .  How do I get my padding to appear around my TABLE element?  I added the surrounding DIV so I could display a background color, but I don't want to change the surrounding DIV if at all possible.

PS - to make this extra complicated, I like the fact that there is no spacing between the cells and I'd like to preserve that.

Comment: Border-spacing doesn't work with border-collapse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`border-collapse` will prevent `padding` from being applied to your table element. I think you'll be fine using `border-spacing: 0;` and dropping `border-collapse`.

I'm assuming you're wrapping your table in a DIV with a background color because you want to create a band of color across the page, rather than simply adding a background color to a table alone.

You have a few options with your approach to add space before and after the table.

#### 1. Use `padding` on the table.

```css
div {
  background-color: orange;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3rem 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Alpha</th>
      <th>Bravo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

#### 2. Use `margin` on the table.

Remember, you'll have to use a clearfix to make sure the margin does not break out of the wrapper DIV.

```css
div {
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: hidden; /* my clearfix */
}

table {
  margin: 3rem auto;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Alpha</th>
      <th>Bravo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

#### 3. Use `padding` on the wrapper DIV.

```css
div {
  padding: 3rem 0;
  background-color: orange;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Alpha</th>
      <th>Bravo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I used your first approach with the padding and it worked beautifully.